# How to get Class from a Type Inference argument?

Tags: java, type-inference

I have a class like this, and want to get the Class as showed by example (which doesn't works) in return of method getClazz. Is it possible?

```
public abstract class SuperTestClass<E> {

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return E.getClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems the same case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unless you have it as a member field of the class.  Due to type-erasure, the generic type is not available at runtime.  Something like this:

```
public class SuperTestClass<E> {

  private final Class<E> genericClass;

  public SuperTestClass(Class<E> genericClass) {
    this.genericClass = genericClass;
  }

  // Changed return type
  public Class<E> getClassType() {
    return this.genericClass;
  }
}


// Subclass
public class TestClass extends SuperTestClass<Connection> {

    public TestClass() {
        super(Connection.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not the "forced" automated way that I though, but it works using no args constructor in subclass calling superclass' constructor with the explicit inference class (like in TestClass).